# Dual Line Form Picker

Tags: swiftui, ios14

I am trying to create a form picker that displays two rows of data / entry. The top row displays correctly showing 2 items with slightly different fonts. The third item is displaying on the second line separated by a horizontal form line. I'm also getting two check marks--one for each line.

```
...
var currCountry: [String] = ["con 1", "con 2", "con 3", "con 4"]
var currSymbol: [String] = ["sym 1", "sym 2", "sym 3", "sym 4"]
var currName: [String] = ["name 1", "name 2", "name 3", "name 4"]

@ObservedObject var userData = UserData()

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Picker("select", selection: $userData.entry) {
                ForEach(0 ..< self.currCountry.count) { i in
                    HStack {
                        Text(currCountry[i])
                            .font(.caption)
                        Text(currSymbol[i])
                            .font(.caption2)
                    }
                    Text(currName[i])
                        .font(.caption2)
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("important info")
    }
}
...
```

Comment: At this point it doesn't appear that I can insert a picture. I would like to have 2 lines of text / entry within the Form Picker window -- a horizontal line two lines of text followed by the next entry horizontal line. Right now the two lines are separated by a horizontal line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure what your question is, so I'll take a leap. Are you referring to that you want to have two items horizontally, and then the third vertical to that? Such as:

```
VStack {
    HStack {
        Text(currCountry[i])
            .font(.caption)
        Text(currSymbol[i])
            .font(.caption2)
    }
    Text(currName[i])
        .font(.caption2)
}
```

This way there is only one checkmark at this point? If this isn't want you were referring to, can you please give an example of what type of output you are looking for.